# Ultrasonic transducer circuit

Tags: transducer

Can someone explain how [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000286441322.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.7aba77e4FsJT78&algo_pvid=28324c67-e6ae-4dc5-9e70-851176fc3c69&algo_expid=28324c67-e6ae-4dc5-9e70-851176fc3c69-27&btsid=56878aee-e3a6-40ac-81a9-fbec5e9a2ebc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_10,searchweb201603_53) work ? I want to make my own ultrasonic bath, but I can't find any useful specs. Do I need some specific circuit to run them or it's just 'plug and play' ?

Comment: if there is no datasheet available, then do not buy

Comment: `plug and play` into what?

Comment: I fail to open the link (without logging in). VtC because it is not clear what this component is, there is no textual or visual support **within** the question. Even with a working link, the link may go dead and the question may go useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It vibrates at 40kHz so of course you need a 40kHz oscillator and a 60W amplifier to drive it.

The specs say: 40kHz and 60W. But the details about the voltage and current required are missing. Maybe because it is cheap and because it is Chinese. The manufacturer might be able to provide a circuit to drive it.

Answer (score 0):

The ultrasonic bath I recently reverse engineered, had an output of 200v at 40khz - 1ma. Hope this helps